# Why my loop is not working in asp.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

Before my question, i'd like to clear that I'm a beginner in Asp.NET.

Here is my Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.Default" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>This is title..</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="loop" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                loop.Text = i.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT***

9

Please help, how to show my loop? Can you please just help me?

Comment: Your loop is working, but it's just showing the last value...

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: change < 10 into <= 10

Comment: It must suppose to show `0123456789`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will loop from **0** to **9** (As it only continues if it is **less than** 10), and set the value as the label's text. Because of this, your code will only show the latest value, which is 9.

If you are looking to create multiple labels, or append the text, those require different code. Your current code simply overwrites the text value each iteration.

To make your expected result, append each value to your text.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   loop.Text += i.ToString();
```

Comment: I think OP meant the label is just displaying "9"

Comment: @ScottSelby Yes, that is what I said in my answer. And no, I did not check out your hat...

Comment: Using `+=`, or the longer version `= label.Text + `, will add the value of `i.ToString()` to `label.Text`. The first time, it will be set to 0, then 1 will be added to it, then 2, and so on.

Comment: lame , i totally had it first , then suggested @Crystal do the same

Answer (score 1):

one option ....

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            loop.Text += i.ToString() + ", ";
        }
```

this will leave the label showing `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ect.`

that is proof the loop happened.  When you are using web forms I don't know what else you expect to happen from one POST , meaning one request sent to the server and one response sent back , so all you can really do is show each iteration of the loop on the label.  Other wise you are going to need a lot more complex methods ,  ( nothing too crazy ) , but based on our question something that you don't know yet .   To make the label keep changniog going up and up

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
loop.Text = i.ToString();
```

is over-writing the text of the loop with the "0", "1", "2", ..., "9" on each iteration. On the final iteration, you set the loop to `"9"` and print that.

The loop is thus working as expected.

To add text to the loop, use `loop.Test += ...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in the page_Load method.

```
loop.Text = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => i.ToString()))
```

Comment: Expected result is without commas